# New version Crosswalk and override onReceivedHttpAuthRequest

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime

How can I override the onReceivedHttpAuthRequest method on new version (> 8) Crosswalk?

Method like this simply doesn't work:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(XWalkView view, XWalkHttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
//(...)
}
```

Error: "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"

It's from:
https://github.com/infil00p/cordova-crosswalk-engine/blob/master/src/android/XWalkCordovaWebViewClient.java

Crosswalk above version has changed API:(